# How can I have different horizontal and vertical scale factor on QWebKit?

Tags: qt, webkit, qtwebkit, qwebkit

We have 2 devices with different screen resolutions (800 x 600 and 800 x 480).  Our client, who has a website fixed to 800 x 600, wanted to display their website on both devices.  I checked QWebView's/QWebFrame methods and there's only one zoomFactor.  Is there a way I can have different zoom factor for vertical and horizontal components?  Thanks!